# Unknown charcode inside text in Javascript causes IndexOf funtion to return -1

Tags: javascript, ascii, indexof, non-ascii-characters, fromcharcode

Below code enters the if clause below,

```
var title = "İnsanlar";
var keyword = "in";
title = title.toLowerCase();

if(title.indexOf(keyword) == -1)
{
  alert(title);
}
```

when I did some debugging, I realised that `title.charCodeAt(1)` returns 775 while `keyword.charCodeAt(1)` returns 110. Which causes my application's search functionality to be broken.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Well, those are indeed different characters. i̇ !== i 

This might be something for RegEx

Comment: maybe check if the characters coming in are actually letters? 


**const isChar = (input) => input.length === 1 && input.match(/[a-z]/i);**

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issue of copy paste text.Don't copy paste value of variable write it down.See below.

https://js.do/code/293600

Comment: Actually in my language, İ and i are the same chacaters, but in computer terms, they are not. I is a different character, so this won't help. But thank you.